# how to take file like object in a file in python

Tags: python, file-io

```
filename = fileobject.read()
```

i want to transfer/assign  the whole data of a object within a file.

Comment: You didn't ask a question or give a meaningful code example. Are you trying to get a filename from a file-like? Write a function that accepts a filename or file-like? Read data from a file?

Comment: An object 'within'? It sounds kinda serialization issue. Is that it? If so, take a look at the 'pickle'/'cpickle' modules.

Comment: Do you want to clone file object?

Answer (score 4):

You are almost doing it correctly already; the code should read

```
filecontent = fileobject.read()
```

read() with no arguments will read the whole data, i.e. the whole file content. The file name has nothing to do with that.